# react-native-android The static Image it look like too big

Tags: react-native

```js
<Image
  style={{backgroundColor: 'rgb(205, 128, 6)'}}
  resizeMode='contain'
  source={require('image!ic_create_black_48dp')}/>
```

in this code `ic_create_black_48dp (96*96px)` it copy from UIExplorer , i put this png to the same folder (res/drawable)。
it doesn't look like a 96*96px size picture.

[image: this is the picture]

in the meantime i tried put the png to drawable-hdpi drawable-xhdpi drawable-xxhdpi

but there is no other effect

Answer (score 0):

For your this type of image you should specify width height as a style property of your component e.g.

```
<Image style={{width:96, height: 96}} src={...}/>
```

Note that on android width/height are in DP not in PX.

In you case it looks like image is in fact small but rendered in a larger container. You can specify how image should behave in that case and for example stretch to the size of component with `resizeMode` style property.

Finally, I recommend you use the new syntax for using static resources documented [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#content), which will make dimensions of the image automatically generated in place of require and would allow you to avoid specifying them in code.